# Missing /root directory in RHEL Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, mount

Somehow `/root` directory is missing(not mounted) in my rhel Linux box.
Can anyone suggest how to re-mount `/root`?

```
bash-3.1# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga).
```

Comment: It would be unusual for `/root` to be mounted on a remote share; please post the output of `grep '/root' /etc/fstab`

Comment: there is no such entry for /root in fstab,
-bash-3.1# grep '/root' /etc/fstab
-bash-3.1#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often /root will simply be a subdirectory of /

Have a look at the last column of `df /root` The output on my machine indicates that /root is a subdirectory of /

If /root is missing the solution may be as simple as logging as root for the first time or running a `mkdir /root`